# Is there a simple way to change multiple names to one single name in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

This is a simplification of my dataframe. The column with colors are characters.

```
|ID|Color |
|--|------| 
|1 |Brown |
|2 |Black |
|3 |Red   |
|4 |Blue  |
|5 |Black |
|6 |Green |
|7 |Brown |
|8 |Red   |
|9 |Yellow|
|10|Violet|
```

I would like to replace all colors that are **NOT** black, brown or red to Other. I have a piece of code that works.

```
library(tidyverse)
df_clean <- df %>%
   mutate(Color = case_when(
      str_detect(Color, "Red") ~ "Other",
      str_detect(Color, "Blue") ~ "Other",
      str_detect(Color, "Green") ~ "Other",
      str_detect(Color, "Yellow") ~ "Other",
      str_detect(Color, "Violet") ~ "Other",
      TRUE ~ Color
))
```

But I would have to do this for all colors (my full dataset has more than 50 color names in >160000 data entries). Is there a simpler way to do this? Like maybe negate() or use ! in the code somewhere? Like say if its not black, brown or red change to Other?

Comment: Take a look at `?"%in%"`. Negation can be done with `!`

Comment: In base R it’s ‘ifelse(!Color %in% c(“black”,”brown”,”red”),”Other”,Color)’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the colors using `%in%`

```
df$Color[!df$Color %in% c('Black', 'Brown', 'Red')] <- 'Other'
```

Can also use `fct_other` from `forcats`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df %>% mutate(Color = fct_other(Color, c('Black', 'Brown', 'Red')))
```